# Como puedo separar mas las distancias entre los td de una tabla?

Tags: html, css

Quiero impirmir los resultados en una tabla, pero los td en donde pongo los titulos se ven muy juntos, como hago para separarlos mas?, ademas mi td nombre tiene un espacio mas grande que los otros, siempre el primer td, aqui les dejo una imagen para que vean a lo que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el codigo:

```
<table id="prueba">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search by name"></input>
                    <a href="index.php?url=login"><button>Back</button></a>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td>Lot:</td>
                <td>Quantity packed:</td>
                <td>Quantity of pallets:</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

por que el td nombre se ve tan espacioso y los otros no? y como puedo crear mas distancia entre ellos? le meti border-collapse: collapse en estilo pero esta asi igual

Answer (score 1):

El td nombre se ve espacioso porque el ancho abarca el ancho del th que contiene el input. Los demás td se ajustan al ancho de la cadena que contienen. Deberías aplicarle estilos css. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<table id="prueba">
   <tr>
      <th>
         <input placeholder="Search by name"></input>
         <a href="index.php?url=login"><button>Back</button></a>
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td>Lot:</td>
      <td>Quantity packed:</td>
      <td>Quantity of pallets:</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Si bien el enlace puede servir para responder la pregunta, se considera de baja calidad responder sin mostrar código que no sea enlace. La pregunta tiene las etiquetas `html` y `css`. Ambas tecnologías son soportadas correctamente por el `snippet` de [es.so]. Podrías escribir un código funcional en el mismo y se vería el resultado, sin necesidad de enlaces externos. Por otro lado la documentación oficial de estas tecnologías no es *w3school* es [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/). Saludos

Comment: Gracias por el consejo [Mauricio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/112837/mauricio-contreras), actualizaré la respuesta con un snippet. Por otro lado, comentarte que [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/) no es una documentación oficial, es simplemente una documentación más.

Comment: Si pero la calidad y reputación del contenido de MDN es infinitamente superior a W3Schools

Answer (score 0):

```
<input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search by name"></input>
<a href="index.php?url=login"><button>Back</button></a>

    <table id="prueba">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Lot:</th>
                <th>Quantity packed:</th>
                <th>Quantity of pallets:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>              
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Cambia bastante si usas mejor las etiquetas, para definir bien tus filas y columnas, td, van a ser los datos que luego tengas en cada columna. Por eso modifique por 
Tambien saque de la tabla tu recuardro buscar y el boton, considero mejor que este antes.

Y luego te dejo un estilo que yo uso mucho para armar grillas, podes modificarlo, pero esta separado cada campo.

```
#prueba {
    width: 100%;    
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#prueba th{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(21, 117, 124);
}

#prueba tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#ddd;
}

#prueba th, td{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;    
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda :)

Comment: En el otro inclui el codigo de CSS, soy nueva, disculpas. Solo intento ayudar! Ahi lo midifique, gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 0):

Con border-spacing puedes lograrlo. En el ejemplo tienes definida una separación de 20px en horizontal entre celdas y de 5px entre filas. IMportante que para usar border-spacing establezcas border-collapse a separate.

```css
table {
  width = 100%
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 20px 5px;
}
td {
   width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<table id="prueba" border="1">
      <th>
         <input placeholder="Search by name"></input>
         <a href="index.php?url=login"><button>Back</button></a>
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td>Lot:</td>
      <td>Quantity packed:</td>
      <td>Quantity of pallets:</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```